# Android Bluetooth: how to detect which slave is disconnected when there are multiple slaves?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Quite a few posts (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584423/how-to-check-if-bluetooth-connection-to-a-device-is-disconnected), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316925/detect-bluetooth-device-disconnected)) on this site have discussed how to detect a lost Bluetooth connection on Android. Essentially, one may register for broadcasts of the actions

- `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED` and
- `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`.

However, when there are multiple slaves, how do I know *which* one of them is disconnected or about to disconnect?

**Edit:**

1. My use case is a multiplayer game.
2. The `BluetoothSocket` class has a method `isConnected()`, which seems useful, but it requires API level 14 (Android 4.0) or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can get to know about the states of devices.
You can use `android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile` interface. It provides an API called `public abstract List<BluetoothDevice> getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates (int[] states)`
which return the list of all the bluetooth devices. You can specify states like `STATE_CONNECTED, STATE_CONNECTING, STATE_DISCONNECTED, STATE_DISCONNECTING` in the argument array.
For more info please see this :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(int[])

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this method when I have time.

Comment: The method is abstract. How can I make use of it? My use case is a multiplayer game in which multiple mobile phones are connected. Although the method you mentioned is implemented in BluetoothA2dp, BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattServer, BluetoothHeadset, BluetoothHealth, these classes do not seem relevant.